# dge list giving NA counts error for transcript id values

Tags: r

I am quite new to R and I am analysing RNA seq data. This is the format of my data frame

```
transcript_id C1 C2 C3 B4 B5 B6 E4 E5 E6 
ENSG00000000003 2019 1619 1597 1343 1026 1010 871 1164 1115 
ENSG00000000005 1 2 1 1 1 2 0 0 0 
ENSG00000000419 1936 1469 1769 2604 2244 2132 2301 2332 2184 
ENSG00000000457 790 826 858 693 561 489 456 615 533 
ENSG00000000460 320 372 362 368 285 282 254 342 265
```

When I use the command

```
data <- DGEList(counts)
```

I get the error

> Error: NA counts not allowed.

I realize that is is because of the transcript_id column, because when I remove it it works fine. Any suggestions? Thank you

```
data <- DGEList(counts)
```

Comment: If you just want to omit the first column, `data <- DGEList(counts[, -1])` should work.

Comment: Yep that was the solution thank you!